# Extending Array in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

How to add a method to a base type, say Array? In the global module this will be recognized

```
interface Array {
   remove(o): Array;
}
```

but where to put the actual implementation?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You can use the prototype to extend Array:

```
interface Array<T> {
    remove(o: T): Array<T>;
}

Array.prototype.remove = function (o) {
    // code to remove "o"
    return this;
}
```

If you are within a module, you will need to make it clear that you are referring to the global `Array<T>`, not creating a local `Array<T>` interface within your module:

```
declare global {
    interface Array<T> {
        remove(o: T): Array<T>;
    }
}
```

Comment: @FrancoisVanderseypen that could be a pain, I suggest you don't try it. It is easier the way proposed here. But if you are curious: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14001136/340760

Comment: it should be `interface Array<T> { remove(o): T[]; }` in new version with generics

Comment: @SteveFenton Hmm, can you elaborate? I can do such things in regular Node modules, why TypeScript forbids that? Do you know any workarounds?

Comment: Definitions must be at the same level in order to take effect, so if you are in a module and you declare `interface Array<T>` that is a member of the module, i.e. `MyModule.Array<T>`. That means the global `Array<T>` is not extended, but a new local interface is created. You have to put extensions in the global scope... I'd suggest putting the interface in a `.d.ts` file. Do you also need to patch the array definition or is it just the interface?

Comment: On typescript 2.4.1 it needs added ```declare global {}``` on the interface declaration, otherwise it will trigger error

Comment: @Pian0_M4n it depends where you add it - if you put it inside an external module then it needs to be forwarded to global, otherwise it appears to be a new interface scoped to the module, for example.

Comment: What if the Array contains a list of objects? And we want to remove it based on that object keys.
e-g;
Person[]
remove(o: [key in Person): T

Answer (score 72):

`declare global` seems to be the ticket as of TypeScript 2.1. Note that `Array.prototype` is of type `any[]`, so if you want to have your function implementation checked for consistency, best to add a generic type parameter yourself.

```
declare global {
  interface Array<T> {
    remove(elem: T): Array<T>;
  }
}

if (!Array.prototype.remove) {
  Array.prototype.remove = function<T>(this: T[], elem: T): T[] {
    return this.filter(e => e !== elem);
  }
}
```

Comment: This does the trick, expect inside the function `this` will be `any[]`, not `T[]`. Does anyone know why? Is there a workaround?

Comment: I added an explicit type to the `this` parameter based on your question. See the "this parameters" section of https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html.

Comment: So how do you import this into another .ts file?

Comment: @Sprotty use import './utils/extensions' e.g. the path to your file with the declaration

Answer (score 22):

Adding to Rikki Gibson's answer,

```
export {}

declare global {
    interface Array<T> {
        remove(elem: T): Array<T>;
    }
}

if (!Array.prototype.remove) {
  Array.prototype.remove = function<T>(elem: T): T[] {
      return this.filter(e => e !== elem);
  }
}
```

Without the `export {}`, you will get the TS error:

```
Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations.
```

Comment: How can we import this? Does "import * as array_extensions" work? or Is there any way to import just some of extension functions?

Comment: @Saleh Use `import "./array_extensions"`

Comment: I wonder why `export {}` helps?

Comment: @tBlabs Because it makes it an "external module", as the error suggests.

Answer (score 8):

From TypeScript 1.6, you can "natively" extend arbitrary expressions like inbuilt types.

[What's new in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#extending-expressions):

> TypeScript 1.6 adds support for classes extending arbitrary expression
>   that computes a constructor function. This means that built-in types
>   can now be extended in class declarations.
>
> The extends clause of a class previously required a type reference to
>   be specified. It now accepts an expression optionally followed by a
>   type argument list. The type of the expression must be a constructor
>   function type with at least one construct signature that has the same
>   number of type parameters as the number of type arguments specified in
>   the extends clause. The return type of the matching construct
>   signature(s) is the base type from which the class instance type
>   inherits. Effectively, this allows both real classes and "class-like"
>   expressions to be specified in the extends clause.

```
// Extend built-in types

class MyArray extends Array<number> { }
class MyError extends Error { }

// Extend computed base class

class ThingA {
    getGreeting() { return "Hello from A"; }
}

class ThingB {
    getGreeting() { return "Hello from B"; }
}

interface Greeter {
    getGreeting(): string;
}

interface GreeterConstructor {
    new (): Greeter;
}

function getGreeterBase(): GreeterConstructor {
    return Math.random() >= 0.5 ? ThingA : ThingB;
}

class Test extends getGreeterBase() {
    sayHello() {
        console.log(this.getGreeting());
    }
}
```

Comment: This leads to problems, in that the `[]` operator fails to behave as expected. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33947854/class-extended-from-built-in-array-in-typescript-1-6-2-does-not-update-length-wh

Comment: The question was how to extend Array.prototype not just class inheritance

Answer (score 6):

#### Extending `Array`

Here is an example to extend `Array` and add the `remove` method to it.
This is a JavaScript example

```js
/** @template T */
class List extends Array {
  /**
   * Remove an item from the list and return the removed item
   * @param {T} item
   * @return {T}
   */
  remove(item) {
    const index = this.indexOf(item);
    if (index === -1) {
      throw new Error(`${item} not in list`);
    }
    this.splice(index, 1);
    return item;
  }
}

const arr = new List(1, 2, 3);
console.log(arr.remove(3)); // 3
console.log(arr); // [1, 2]
```

And this is a TypeScript example.

I've added a constructor and pushed the arguments of it to the array. (Couldn't do it with `super(...items)`!

```
class List<T> extends Array {
  constructor(...items: T[]) {
    super();
    this.push(...items);
  }

  public remove(item: T): T {
    const index = this.indexOf(item);
    if (index === -1) {
      throw new Error(`${item} not in list`);
    }
    this.splice(index, 1);
    return item;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just tried it with TypeScript and it worked very well and is very OOP idiomatic.

Comment: This is not extending Array, it is 'just' a subclass that adds a remove function. The name List is not well-chosen, as it is not really a 'list', in the general sense typical for naming programming paradigms. A list would suggest something like a linked list, with at least a bit more usage than just an Array with .remove function.

Answer (score 4):

```
class MyArray<T> extends Array<T> {
    remove: (elem: T) => Array<T> = function(elem: T) {
        return this.filter(e => e !== elem);
    }
}
let myArr = new MyArray<string>();
myArr.remove("some");
```

this works for me with typescript v2.2.1!

Comment: This problem with this approach is that now every array has to be of the type `MyArray`, so it won't work seamlessly with other libraries that return arrays.

Comment: The question was how to extend Array.prototype not just class inheritance