# Getting around Typescript with ngImgCrop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm new to coding and have the opportunity to do some small stories on a project to whet my teeth. Right now I'm working on getting profile picture selection and cropping into a webapp with AngularJS. I've selected ngImgCropper to handle the cropping. Here's a JSFiddle with boilerplate code: http://jsfiddle.net/a2ew3yhf/50/

And here's JavaScript from that link:

```
var handleFileSelect=function(evt) {
  var file=evt.currentTarget.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (evt) {
    $scope.$apply(function($scope){
        $scope.myImage = evt.currentTarget.result;
    });
  };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
};
```

Here's my problem. My project uses Typescript, which doesn't support evt.currentTarget.result, so I get the following error:

```
Property 'result' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'
```

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: So, I'm curious, too. I see that you can modify typescript.d.ts, but as typescript is a dependency installed from NPM, there's no sense in altering it. should pull requests be submitted to the TSD repository ? Here's a related post on adding definitions to built-ins. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23636093/add-method-to-array-in-typescript-1-0

Comment: Maybe could make your own TSD file for ngImgCrop and define the object on event.target... load it in from tsd.d.ts. If you wanted to go further, you could create a tsd repository on github for ngImgCrop so that it worked through official TSD repository, but not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

### Simple solution

If you sure that this property exist just make something like below

```
 var handleFileSelect=function(evt) {
      var file=evt.currentTarget.files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (evt) {
             $scope.$apply(function($scope){
                  $scope.myImage = (<any>evt.currentTarget).result;
              });
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
 };
```

Also you can create own interface that would be describe your target

```
  interface MyTarget {
        result:any;   //or type of image
  } 
  //skip some code
 $scope.myImage = (evt.currentTarget as MyTarget).result;
```

### Complicated solution

You can provide own declaration of  ngImageCroper or provide description for current event

```
   var handleFileSelect=function(evt: ImageCropEvent){
        //your    stuff
   }
```

### Resource

1. [Write your d.ts file](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#writing-dts-files)

Comment: Nick, the `<any>` here casts the evt.currentTarget as a "generic" with no type. This is how you'd get around the compiler error.