# Class extended from built-in Array in Typescript 1.6.2 does not update length while using [] operator

Tags: javascript, typescript, extends

it should be possible to extend build-in types in ts 1.6 as I read [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#extending-expressions):

> TypeScript 1.6 adds support for classes extending arbitrary expression that computes a constructor function. This means that built-in types can now be extended in class declarations.
>
> ...
>
> Some examples:
>
> ```
> // Extend built-in types
>
> class MyArray extends Array<number> { }
> class MyError extends Error { }
>
> ...
> ```

However when extending Array, length property is not updated while using [] operator to set values. Push function works fine, but I need [] operator.

My Example:

```
class ExtendedArray<T> extends Array<T> {}

var buildinArray = new Array<string>();
var extendedArray = new ExtendedArray<string>();

buildinArray.push("A");
console.log(buildinArray.length); // 1 - OK
buildinArray[2] = "B";
console.log(buildinArray.length); // 3 - OK

extendedArray.push("A");
console.log(extendedArray.length); // 1 - OK
extendedArray[2] = "B";
console.log(extendedArray.length); // 1 - FAIL
console.dir(extendedArray); // both values, but wrong length
```

Am I doing something wrong? Where is the problem?

Comment: What's your use case for extending `Array`? I've never felt the need to subclass arrays especially in TypeScript where the interfaces are extremely versatile when it comes to generics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code translates to this JavaScript code:

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
};
var ExtendedArray = (function (_super) {
    __extends(ExtendedArray, _super);
    function ExtendedArray() {
        _super.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    return ExtendedArray;
})(Array);
var buildinArray = new Array();
var extendedArray = new ExtendedArray();
buildinArray.push("A");
console.log(buildinArray.length); // 1 - OK
buildinArray[2] = "B";
console.log(buildinArray.length); // 3 - OK
extendedArray.push("A");
console.log(extendedArray.length); // 1 - OK
extendedArray[2] = "B";
console.log(extendedArray.length); // 1 - FAIL
console.dir(extendedArray); // both values, but wrong length
```

[[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20ExtendedArray%3CT%3E%20extends%20Array%3CT%3E%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20buildinArray%20%3D%20new%20Array%3Cstring%3E()%3B%0D%0Avar%20extendedArray%20%3D%20new%20ExtendedArray%3Cstring%3E()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AbuildinArray.push(%22A%22)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(buildinArray.length)%3B%20%2F%2F%201%20-%20OK%0D%0AbuildinArray%5B2%5D%20%3D%20%22B%22%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(buildinArray.length)%3B%20%2F%2F%203%20-%20OK%0D%0A%0D%0AextendedArray.push(%22A%22)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(extendedArray.length)%3B%20%2F%2F%201%20-%20OK%0D%0AextendedArray%5B2%5D%20%3D%20%22B%22%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(extendedArray.length)%3B%20%2F%2F%201%20-%20FAIL%0D%0Aconsole.dir(extendedArray)%3B%20%2F%2F%20both%20values%2C%20but%20wrong%20length)]

The problem is that the bracket notation is not copied as part of copying of `Array` prototype:

> In JavaScript, we can sub-class native data types by extending the
>   native prototypes. This works perfectly with the native String object;
>   but, when it comes to native Arrays, things don't work quite so
>   nicely. If we extend the Array prototype, we inherit the native array
>   functions; but, we no longer have the ability to use bracket notation
>   to set and get indexed values within the given array. Sure, we can use
>   push() and pop() to overcome this limitation; but, if we want to keep
>   the bracket notation feature functional, we have to build on top of an
>   existing array instance rather than truly sub-classing the Array
>   object.

[[Source](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2292-extending-javascript-arrays-while-keeping-native-bracket-notation-functionality.htm)]

There is an in-depth [discussion and solutions here](http://www.2ality.com/2013/03/subclassing-builtins-es6.html) by Dr. Axel Rauschmayer.

Answer (score 1):

Extending `Array` is only supported in ES6 environments, so if you've set the `compilerSettings.target` of your `tsconfig.json` to ES3 or ES5 this won't work properly. There are [workarounds](http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch28.html) in ES5 but I'd say it isn't worth the trouble - although you can probably use it in TypeScript since it is a superset of ES5. [This book on ES6](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_classes.html#subclassing-builtin-constructors) explains the situation in more detail.