# Extending Array primitive in typescript (angular-cli project)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli, extend

I need the ability to easily sort collections and I've chosen to extend the Array primitive. I realize this is considered bad practice in most cases, but this will be used only internally (not a shared lib). No matter what approach I've tried I'm not getting a working result. I keep getting the error: `TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property`. This is a simplified example of my latest iteration. I have a more complete version of this working [in the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Array%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%24sortBy(sortKey%3A%20string)%3A%20T%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%24sortKey%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%24reversed%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(!Array.prototype.%24sortBy)%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Object.defineProperties(Array.prototype%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'%24sortBy'%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%20function%20(sortKey)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(sortKey%20%3D%3D%3D%20this.%24sortKey)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.reverse()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.%24reversed%20%3D%20true%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.%24reversed%20%3D%20false%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.%24sortKey%20%3D%20sortKey%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.sort(function%20(a%2C%20b)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20this%20will%20be%20replaced%20by%20a%20more%20complex%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20alphanumeric%2Fnatural%20sort%20method%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(a%5BsortKey%5D%20%3C%20b%5BsortKey%5D)%20%7B%20return%20-1%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(a%5BsortKey%5D%20%3E%20b%5BsortKey%5D)%20%7B%20return%201%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%200%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'%24sortKey'%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20writable%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%20null%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'%24reversed'%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20writable%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%20false%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20people%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7Bname%3A%20'dick'%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7Bname%3A%20'alice'%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7Bname%3A%20'zed'%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7Bname%3A%20'barry'%7D%0D%0A%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20original%0D%0Aconsole.log(%60Original%3A%20%24%7BJSON.stringify(people)%7D%60)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20sorted%0D%0Alet%20people1%20%3D%20people.slice().%24sortBy('name')%0D%0Aconsole.log(%60Sorted%3A%20%24%7BJSON.stringify(people1)%7D%60)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20reversed%0D%0Alet%20people2%20%3D%20people.slice().%24sortBy('name')%3B%0D%0Apeople2.%24sortBy('name')%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(%60Reversed%3A%20%24%7BJSON.stringify(people2)%7D%60)%3B%0D%0A) so I'm assuming he problem lies with the angular-cli config/build process???

```ts
interface Array<T> {
  $sortBy(sortKey:string): T[];
}

if (!Array.prototype['$sortBy']) {

  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, '$sortBy', {
    value: function(sortKey) {
      return this.sort( function(a, b) { // TypeError here???
        if (a[sortKey] < b[sortKey]) { return -1; }
        if (a[sortKey] > b[sortKey]) { return 1; }
        return 0;
      });
    }
  }

}
```

I've also tried this approach but my IDE (VSCode) gives me the error: `[ts] Property '$sortBy' does not exist on type 'any[]'.`

```ts
         Intellisense error here
                   |
                   V
Array.prototype.$sortBy = function(sortKey:string){
  return this.sort( function(a, b) {
    ...
  });
}
```

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es2016"
    ]
  }
}
```

*tsconfig.app.json*

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
  "lib": [
    "es2016",
    "dom"
  ],
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Which version of typescript are you using? What's your `tsconfig.json`? Your code works fine in playground.

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/basarat/typescript-collections has something that would suit your needs better. I haven't tried the array utilities but the data structures are nice.

Comment: Checkout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000645/how-to-extend-native-javascript-array-in-typescript Starting in TypeScript 1.6, you can extend the Array type

Comment: @NitzanTomer added my ts configs above. I'm using TS 2.1.6. This is an angular-cli project

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. It works fine for me

Comment: Also, regardless of your problem, extending of the `Array<T>` interface needs to be outside of the `if (!Array.prototype['$sortBy'])`

Comment: Thanks @osi but it looks like that approach causes problems... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33947854/class-extended-from-built-in-array-in-typescript-1-6-2-does-not-update-length-wh

Comment: Thanks @NitzanTomer I updated my example. Still can't figure out what the problem is. I'm assuming it's a problem with my environment.

Comment: Your 2nd approach (`Array.prototype.$sortBy = ...`) indeed fails if you extend the `Array<T>` interface inside the `if`, but when it's above it, then the compilation error goes away.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well, so just pasting my results here in case someone needs.

in your `main.ts` file add this:

```js
// Here will be all extension methods that will be shared globally across the app
declare global {
  interface Array<T> {
    sortAlphaNumeric(fieldName: string): Array<T>;
  }
}
```

then you can create a file with this:

```js
    /** 
     * The extension of Array type allows to sort AlphaNumeric data
     * @param fieldName {string} requires the field name which you want to sort by
     */
    Array.prototype.sortAlphaNumeric = function (fieldName: string) {
        return this.sort((a, b) => {
            return a[fieldName].toLowerCase().localeCompare(b[fieldName].toLowerCase(), undefined, {
                numeric: true,
                sensitivity: 'base'
            });
        });
    };
```