# TypeScript - Array sort extension method

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I'm looking to create an array extension "sort" method in TypeScript where the array could be made of various object types. I could call this extension method from any component.

This sort needs to take in an object property to sort by (the property could be number or string of course) and the direction that's an enumerated type (ascending 1 or descending -1).  I have the arrays, I have the enum for sortDirection.  But where/how do I build the sort method to call it like this?

```
myArrayOfObjects.sort('name', sortDirection.Descending);
```

Here's my existing component-level sort that I'm trying to turn into an extension method that I could call from anywhere.  It's easy enough to turn the direction into an enum and pass that it, but I'm really trying to make this an extension method:

```
 sort(property: string): void {
    this.isDescending = !this.isDescending;
    this.column = property;
    const direction = this.isDescending ? 1 : -1;

    this.searchResults.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (a[property] < b[property]) {
            return -1 * direction;
        } else if (a[property] > b[property]) {
            return 1 * direction;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    });
    this.currentPage = 0;
}
```

this.searchResults is below, but it could be any array or any object with properties. Again, this is currently a component-level function that I want to turn into an extension method for arrays:

```
@Input() searchResults: IPersonSummary[];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extending Array in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802383/extending-array-in-typescript)

Answer (score 4):

Because TypeScript have loaded base typings where method with name sort is defined you can't redefine it with the same name. If you consider to use some little different name (in example I choose mySort) you can do that. You need to define it in Array interface and assign your function to Array prototype.
Define extend with new name is best practise because you cant call base method anytimesince you override some base method. If you consider to call base method sometime in the future you will get into big trouble.

Recommended way to do it:

```
interface Array<T> {
    mySort(property: string): void;
}

Array.prototype.mySort = function (property: string): void {
    this.isDescending = !this.isDescending;
    this.column = property;
    const direction = this.isDescending ? 1 : -1;

    this.searchResults.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (a[property] < b[property]) {
            return -1 * direction;
        } else if (a[property] > b[property]) {
            return 1 * direction;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    });
    this.currentPage = 0;
}
```