# TypeScript: Extending a native class gives incorrect prototype

Tags: typescript

### Question

In TypeScript, when I do:

```js
class B { ... }
class A extends B { ... }
```

I can call methods/getters/setters of prototype A normally, without error.

However, when I do the same thing with native class:

```js
class A extends Array { ... }
```

When I call methods/getters/setters of prototype A, it throws because properties in prototype A are all undefined.

Why?

### Examples

Given this working code:

```js
class Animal {

  protected name: string;
  protected age: number;

  constructor(name: string, age: number){
    this.name = name;
  }

  eat(){
    console.log(`${this.name} has eaten.`);
  }

  sleep(){
    console.log(`${this.name} has slept.`);
  }

}

class Dog extends Animal {

  constructor(...args: [string, number]){
    super(...args);
  }

  bark(){
    console.log(`${this.name} has barked.`);
  }

}

const dog = new Dog('doggo', 2);
dog.eat();
dog.bark();
```

It will be transpiled into:

```js
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
    var extendStatics = function (d, b) {
        extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
            ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
            function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
        return extendStatics(d, b);
    };
    return function (d, b) {
        extendStatics(d, b);
        function __() { this.constructor = d; }
        d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
    };
})();
var Animal = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Animal(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    Animal.prototype.eat = function () {
        console.log(this.name + " has eaten.");
    };
    Animal.prototype.sleep = function () {
        console.log(this.name + " has slept.");
    };
    return Animal;
}());
var Dog = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(Dog, _super);
    function Dog() {
        var args = [];
        for (var _i = 0; _i < arguments.length; _i++) {
            args[_i] = arguments[_i];
        }
        return _super.apply(this, args) || this;
    }
    Dog.prototype.bark = function () {
        console.log(this.name + " has barked.");
    };
    return Dog;
}(Animal));
var dog = new Dog('doggo', 2);
dog.eat();
dog.bark();
```

So far, so good.

Now when I try to extend a native class (in this case, `Array`):

```js
class List<T> extends Array<T> {

  private index: number;

  constructor(...items: T[]) {
    super(...items);
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'index', {
      value: 0,
      writable: true,
      configurable: true
    });
  }

  get current() {
    return this[this.index];
  }

  get max() {
    return this.length - 1;
  }

  next() {
    return this.index === this.max
      ? this.first()
      : this[++this.index];
  }

  prev() {
    return this.index === 0
      ? this.last()
      : this[--this.index];
  }

  first() {
    return this[this.index = 0];
  }

  last() {
    return this[this.index = this.max];
  }

}

const list = new List(1, 2, 3);
console.log('List:', list);
console.log('Length:', list.length);
console.log('Current value:', list.current);
console.log('Next value:', list.next());
```

It gets transpiled into this code that throws:

```js
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
    var extendStatics = function (d, b) {
        extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
            ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
            function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
        return extendStatics(d, b);
    };
    return function (d, b) {
        extendStatics(d, b);
        function __() { this.constructor = d; }
        d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
    };
})();
var List = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(List, _super);
    function List() {
        var items = [];
        for (var _i = 0; _i < arguments.length; _i++) {
            items[_i] = arguments[_i];
        }
        var _this = _super.apply(this, items) || this;
        Object.defineProperty(_this, 'index', {
            value: 0,
            writable: true,
            configurable: true
        });
        return _this;
    }
    Object.defineProperty(List.prototype, "current", {
        get: function () {
            return this[this.index];
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
    Object.defineProperty(List.prototype, "max", {
        get: function () {
            return this.length - 1;
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
    List.prototype.next = function () {
        return this.index === this.max
            ? this.first()
            : this[++this.index];
    };
    List.prototype.prev = function () {
        return this.index === 0
            ? this.last()
            : this[--this.index];
    };
    List.prototype.first = function () {
        return this[this.index = 0];
    };
    List.prototype.last = function () {
        return this[this.index = this.max];
    };
    return List;
}(Array));
var list = new List(1, 2, 3);
console.log('List:', list);
console.log('Length:', list.length);
console.log('Current value:', list.current);
console.log('Next value:', list.next());
```

Why?

Answer (score 2):

I see you are targeting ES5. When transpiling to ESNext your code will perfectly work as expected. If you need to target ES5 and extend native types (such as `Array`) you will have to set in the constructor the prototype of your own class ([Object.setPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf)).

```js
class List<T> extends Array<T> {

  constructor(...items: T[]) {
    super(...items);
    // ...
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, Object.create(List.prototype)); // (Object as any).setPrototypeOf
  }

  // ...

}
```

Check the console in the 
[playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/play?target=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEAyCWEAuAeAKgPmgUwB5OwDsATGAQQCcKwBPdLAbwCgnpoAHC+ANzAOngk8ALmiEArgFsARtgrQAvNAAMAbhZtgAe0LIK44Ei0UAFADoL8ApIii0AbQC6ASmjM2bCOPZzzl6xDO6h7QAPLSAFbYhmbE2ABmgtgAChRaPhRINCZIABaIADTQAOSCcbjFRe4h0Lwg4tiiygWsNQDuXEhg0iCN0Ej62C010NqEiQDm4tQ9fQMNrWwAvkGL0CbhUYbQkDuENM5mENhIqVpGWT6h8Tn5EEWb0UhmwBTYfNgmCMhmnOfnNB8zlWyw00AmJ1G0zehCQJlc1TYbyQ00I-Tu9jyiDMZTwjmC0CWYIhSGgkjAuHhbjWyNR6OxvUIEzy0AAtNAAIwEomtQh4OEImknOlYiA4oS4RQKJSiszk3BrNgAfnpYsSFGQ8MV0FEovsAGp9bLcbh8a0eWxONhuFTEdBaRQ0caJVKlMptSrZeBNc5tbqMazWc7ymbQa11T7qSEHU6McG8IoVKHCWDvQKox4Y6rMXdxeVE7L5cmeTyxshoCBEKSlHy2nAqyYOUUAExFADMqzLWl6ZhAWgmJmK3yQwkqFarnZ0EG72F7-cHsCIzNyo6KlZ+jOXk90M7nA+KAGFoURSXUGqvxz9gMfYdvpz2+-uAHL82pgeqNMfr558-Dw1YsF2D7zt+Ai6F0hDANgWjxPWyBBNAAD0iH9IMQA).

Check also another [useful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802383/extending-array-in-typescript) on how to extend native types like `Array`.