# Extending Array in TypeScript for specific type

Tags: arrays, typescript, types

I know how to extend array for any type:

```
declare global {
  interface Array<T> {
    remove(elem: T): Array<T>;
  }
}

if (!Array.prototype.remove) {
  Array.prototype.remove = function<T>(this: T[], elem: T): T[] {
    return this.filter(e => e !== elem);
  }
}
```

Source: [Extending Array in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802383/extending-array-in-typescript)

But is there also a way to extend the array **only for a specific type?**. Like only for arrays of type `User` -> `Array<User>`.

I want to create a extend method, like `.toUsersMap()` and this method should not be displayed for arrays, which have not the type `User`.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve similar behaviour:

```js
type User = {
  tag: 'User'
}

interface Array<T> {
  toUsersMap: T extends User ? (elem: T) => Array<T> : never
}

declare var user: User;

const arr = [user]

arr.toUsersMap(user) // ok

const another_array = [{ notUser: true }]

another_array.toUsersMap() // This expression is not callable
```

If `T` parameter does not extends `User`, TS will disallow using `toUsersMap`

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gKClYBDAcwC4oByeJUzAX00wEsA7YJAMzwGNoBBRRPEAB4AKgD4M2XAHsKiOAFk8YEsKgQAHi0YATOLATIA-FAAUEADYQAtioCUqcb35CxUEowgA3JDTraIHOZ4iNCewVAArgYksgDcdBxSjHDAUMHIaADaUUgAunTpAHTAMgYKSiY5iPYA9DVQUgDWCUkpaYxSwAAWSAD66QKoUJnoUB3AsiTAiBHQ1PmYeOM9iP18AsWlSOVgJrX1wl30ehpgIXBw9ElQx2OdUBx45kEARpZAA)

Comment: You can also use [a `this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) like [so](https://tsplay.dev/NrvQlN).

Comment: @jcalz I believe your solution is much better than mine. Please provide an answer

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to completely suppress the IntelliSense prompting for `toUsersMap()` on `Array`s, but you can definitely make it a compiler error to call `arr.toUsersMap()` unless `arr` is assignable to `Array<User>`.  One way to do this is to give the `toUsersMap()` method a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types):

```
interface Array<T> {
  toUsersMap(this: Array<User>): Map<string, User>;
}
```

Now the compiler will require that `toUsersMap()` only be called with a `this` context of something assignable to `Array<User>`:

```
interface User {
  username: string;
}
const arr = [{ username: "foo" }, { username: "bar" }];
arr.toUsersMap() // okay, no error

const another_array = ["hello", 123];
another_array.toUsersMap() // error, 
//~~~~~~~~~~~ <--
// The 'this' context of type '{ notUser: boolean; }[]' is 
// not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'User[]'
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChnICumUIcAthAFzLphSgDmA3LgL666iSyIoCCUKHACeAHgAqAPhz5kYAPYZo6ALJwADgAowAC2Doag4eOVQpAShrqNYugxCMANGhJTWHXAgUg6yOELIALzIANrYRCRklDQARDAKCrHIbC4RxNDR1MixAEYByWwAuqwBUAB0imZqmloWyAD0DcgKANac3r5g-iAKetAA+mWiwWGxuhAANpNJLgCMAEwAzCW4cL39UENCopVKJDXa9U3I0FAKUC64JxITyADkegb3yJ2QAB7dCjDyIhoo9wiGzMNFyiUmEHWzBSoSKLwMyA2-nQ6GAjDIuQh8gUyEoegUABN7ugHk90C9vr9-g8zLD7pwgA)