# TypeScript: Array prototype extension gives error in react native [Recursive Array | Array] style of components

Tags: arrays, typescript, react-native

[Error Screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2c1F.png)

**TS Error Message:**
No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 2, '(props: ViewProps | Readonly): View', gave the following error.
Type 'ViewStyle[]' is not assignable to type 'StyleProp'.
Type 'ViewStyle[]' is not assignable to type 'RecursiveArray<ViewStyle | Falsy | RegisteredStyle>'.
Types of property 'toggleItem' are incompatible.
Type '(element: ViewStyle, predicate?: ViewStyle | PredicateCallback | undefined, thisArg?: any) => ....

```
#Array.extention.ts
/* eslint-disable no-extend-native */
export {};

type PredicateCallback<T> = (value: T, index: number, obj: T[]) => boolean;

declare global {
  interface Array<T> {
    /**
     * Returns the elements of an array with toggled element that meet the condition specified in a predicate function.
     * @param element The element to toggle for.
     * @param predicate Default value is element.
     * find calls predicate once for each element of the array, in ascending
     * order, until it finds one where predicate returns true. If such an element is found,
     * @param thisArg If provided, it will be used as the this value for each invocation of
     * predicate. If it is not provided, undefined is used instead.
     */
    toggleItem(
      element: T,
      predicate?: PredicateCallback<T> | T,
      thisArg?: any,
    ): T[];
  }
}

Array.prototype.toggleItem = function (element, predicate = element, thisArg) {
  let newArray = [...this];
  let index = -1;
  if (typeof predicate === typeof element) {
    index = newArray.indexOf(predicate);
  } else {
    index = newArray.findIndex(predicate, thisArg);
  }
  if (index > -1) {
    newArray.splice(index, 1);
  } else {
    newArray.push(element);
  }
  return newArray;
};
```

```
#App.ts
import './utils/Array.extension';
```

Reference(Answer: Rikki Gibson): https://stackoverflow.com/a/41413433/13207082

Help me to fix this ts error.