# How to create a method/function for array/object

Tags: javascript

This is my first question, so please be gentle.

I'm trying to create an array of objects, where the object includes a method/function to retrieve data.

So eventually I don't want to use `getFirstName(arrayName, arrayNumber)`, but instead use something like

```
aliens[x].getFirstName;
```

or

```
persons.first.getFirstName;
```

If it's not possible in Javascript, or possible in this manner, please suggest the next best thing.

```
var persons = [

{
    firstname : "John",
    lastname  : "Doe",
    age       : 50,
    eyecolor  : "blue",
},

{
    firstname : "Jane",
    lastname  : "Siyabonga",
    age       : 39,
    eyecolor  : "brown",
},
]

var aliens = [

{
    firstname : "Bob",
    lastname  : "the Alien",
    age       : 350,
    eyecolor  : "yellow",
},

{
    firstname : "xblanque",
    lastname  : "the Predator",
    age       : 19,
    eyecolor  : "red",
},

]

function getFirstName(arrayName, arrayNumber)
{
    var x = arrayName[arrayNumber].firstname;
    return x;
}

Array.prototype.getLastName=function()
{
    var x = this.lastname;
    return x;
}
```

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11422041/1930331) that deals with the same question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ECMAscript supports `getter` and `setter` methods. In any *ES5* compatible implementation, we can use it like

```
var obj = {
    foo: 42,
    bar: 32,
    get getFoo() {
        return this.foo;
    },
    get sum() {
        return this.foo + this.bar;
    }
};
```

now we can acces it like

```
obj.getFoo;  // 42
obj.sum;     // 74
```

---

Another way to create those is *ES5*'s `Object.defineProperty`. For instance:

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'getBar', {
    get: function() {
        return this.bar;
    }
});
```

Comment: getters and setters are great!

Comment: I have never heard of ECMAscript, as I am a self-taught programmer.
I'm going to google it now, but I'd like to know if it's default in all/most browsers ? IF I were to use this, would it work ?

Comment: @MisterBrownZA: ECMAscript and JavaScript are one of a kind. For the compatibility, it will work in all latest browsers 100%. It will also work in older versions for most browsers. Only legacy browsers like IE 6-7 might have a problem with this syntax.

Answer (score 1):

`aliens[x].firstname;` works fine. But, as @jAndy suggested, you can make use of getters and setters, like any OOP language.

```
function Alien( firstname, lastname, age, eyecolor) { // constructor

    // ...

    this.getFirstName = function() {
        return firstname;
    };
}

var aliens = [
    new Alien("Bob", "the Alien", 350, "yellow"),
    new Alien("xblanque", "the Predator", 19, "red")
];

console.log(aliens[0].getFirstName()); // will output "Bob"
```

Also, beware `Array.prototype` manipulation: you are adding `getLastName` method to **any** array present in your code.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, and thought that it was wrong.
Just to confirm, when you say new Alien("","","","")
are you calling the function from above, or are you creating an object?

Comment: @MisterBrownZA Creating a object, because I'm using `Alien` as constructor function. You must understand that in Javascript *everything* behaves like a object. About functions, you must pay attention to the concept of "closure". When a function is called with operator `new`, a object is allocated in closure of function and its reference is `this`. Also, `new` ensures that `this` will be returned.